# Meaning of "tap dry" in "wash the 96-well ELISA plate using a plate washer and tap dry"

Tags: terminology

From a qPCR instruction:

> Wash the plate once with 300 μL of IX PBST using a plate washer and **tap dry**.

What is the meaning of **tap dry**? This is an ELISA plate (biotechnology). The phrase comes up several times in my document.

Does it mean "to give slight blows to the plate to shed all liquid from it"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's how you dry ELISA plates.

> Problem: Too much signal in ELISA
>
> Possible Cause: Insufficient washing
>
> Solution:
> Use appropriate washing procedure [...] At the end of each
> washing step, invert plate on absorbent tissue and allow to completely
> drain, **tapping forcefully** if necessary to remove any residual
> fluid.

[ELISA Troubleshooting Guide (ThermoFisher)](https://www.thermofisher.com/uk/en/home/life-science/protein-biology/protein-biology-learning-center/protein-biology-resource-library/pierce-protein-methods/overview-elisa/elisa-troubleshooting-guide.html)

You can (e.g.) pat, tap, rub, wipe, blow, shake (etc) something dry, that is, perform the action so that the item becomes dry.